# How to remove whitespace from a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings where I need all white space for each item trimmed if it is more than one white space.

```
original = ['1   0    1', 'how is it \n going?', 'hey how are you      today?', '0']
without_spaces = [item.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True) for item in original]
```

My expected output is:

```
print(original)
['1 0 1', 'how is it going?', 'hey how are you today?', '0']
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: The first item in your expected output does not match what you describe. rather, it should be `"1 0 1"`

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.  Fixing it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub()` for this purpose:

```
import re
original = ['1   0    1', 'how is it \n going?', 'hey how are you      today?', '0']
without_spaces = [re.sub('\s+', ' ', item) for item in original]
print(without_spaces)
```

the output will be:

```
['1 0 1', 'how is it going?', 'hey how are you today?', '0']
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
' '.join(mystring.split())
```

This will split by in words and join them back into a single string using `" "`.

Another approach would be:

```
import re

re.sub('\s+', ' ', mystring).strip()
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
import re
original = ['1   0    1', 'how is it \n going?', 'hey how are you      today?', '0']
without_spaces = [re.sub("\s+", " ", item) for item in original]

print(without_spaces)
```